# mysqlのクエリにおいて、「①の結果がなければ、②の条件で探す」というような表現は可能でしょうか。

Tags: mysql

条件
⓪ある１つのカラム(親テーブルの外部キー)の値ごとにデータを取得したい
＋
①現在日付より前の日付があれば最も新しい日付のレコードを抽出する
②①に該当するものがなかった場合、現在日付よりも後の日付で最も古い日付のレコードを抽出する

上記のような条件で各外部キーのカラムごとに１レコードだけ抽出するようなクエリが書きたいのですが、
現状以下に書いたクエリで、各外部キーごとに①もしくは②に合致するレコードを返すものを書いたのですが、この場合外部キーのカラムごとに最大2レコード返ってしまいます。この結果をプログラム側でやりくりすれば取りたいデータは取れなくはなさそうなのですが、
INとサブクエリを利用しているのでパフォーマンスが悪そうなので、もっと上手い方法をご存知の方がいれば教えていただきたく、質問させていただきました。

ご回答よろしくお願いいたします。

```
CREATE TABLE `parent` (
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '親テーブルID'
) COMMENT='親テーブル';

CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `child_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id',
  `switching_date` date NOT NULL COMMENT '切替日',
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '親テーブルID'
) COMMENT='子テーブル';
```

```
SELECT * FROM child 
WHERE 
(
(child.parent_id,child.switching_date) 
IN (
SELECT parent_id,MAX(switching_date) AS switching_date FROM child AS latest_child 
WHERE latest_child.switching_date <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d')
GROUP BY latest_child.parent_id
ORDER BY switching_date DESC 
) 
OR 
(child.parent_id,child.switching_date) 
IN (
SELECT parent_id,MIN(switching_date) AS switching_date FROM child AS future_child 
WHERE future_child.switching_date > DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d')
GROUP BY future_child.parent_id
ORDER BY switching_date DESC 
)
)
GROUP BY child.parent_id,child.switching_date
ORDER BY child.switching_date ASC ;
```

Comment: SQLの質問をする際にはテーブル定義も記述した方が回答を得られやすいかと思います。現状では回答者はSQLからテーブル定義を推理しなければなりません。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。簡易的ですが、テーブル定義とそれに合わせて自分で作成したSQLを修正しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

①と②の条件で親テーブルと[外部結合(SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/038440/1)して、[`ifnull`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)で過去日がなければ未来日を表示する方法があります。

下記のサンプルSQLでは、`left join`のwhere句で最新テーブルA(`PAST_A`)と未来テーブルA(`FUTURE_A`)を抽出しし、`ifnull`を使って過去日がなければ未来日を表示しています。

#### サンプルSQL

```
select   p.id as id,
         -- ifnullで ①最新テーブルの該当レコードがなければ②未来テーブルの該当レコードを表示
         ifnull(max(PAST_A.post_date), min(FUTURE_A.post_date)) as post_data
from     PARENT P
         left join A PAST_A    -- 最新テーブルA
         on P.id = PAST_A.p_id and PAST_A.post_date < current_date()
         left join A FUTURE_A  -- 未来テーブルA
         on P.id = FUTURE_A.p_id and FUTURE_A.post_date >= current_date()
group by p.id
order by post_data asc
```

#### サンプルSQLのテーブル構成例

```
create table PARENT (  -- 親テーブル
  id int primary key
);

create table A (
  id int,
  post_date date,  -- 日付カラム
  p_id int,        -- 親テーブル外部キーカラム
  foreign key (p_id) references PARENT(id)
);

insert into PARENT values(1);
insert into PARENT values(2);
insert into PARENT values(3);

insert into A values(1, date_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day), 1);  -- 昨日
insert into A values(2, date_sub(current_date(), interval 2 day), 1);  -- 一昨日

insert into A values(3, date_add(current_date(), interval 1 day), 2);  -- 明日
insert into A values(4, date_add(current_date(), interval 2 day), 2);  -- 明後日

insert into A values(5, date_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day), 3);  -- 昨日
insert into A values(6, current_date(), 3);                            -- 今日
```

Comment: 意図しているデータの抽出が行え、処理時間も自分で作成したものより早くなりました。